# How can I get data from other websites?

Tags: python, database, parsing, web-scraping

I want to create a website that extracts information from other websites and print them into my website, I am on research step, so I would like to hear some opinions and what's the best solution to this project?

I have heard that Python using parser can do this I just want to know what's the path I should take and which language should I use?.

Comment: Web sites that allow and encourage the use of their data offer better methods than scraping such as API, RSS etc.  If you have to scrape, you are likely violating terms of use and/or copyright provisions.

Comment: I want to get specific information from other websites to summarize them and provide in my website and if the user want to read the whole information he will be able to get to the main source. And I am always give all credit to the place where the user got the summarized information. I don't know if that's still violating copyright provision.

Answer (score 4):

Python with BeautifulSoup and Urllib2 will probably serve you well. Of course, it is questionable as to whether or not you should be scraping data from other websites and you might find yourself in a constant struggle if those websites change layouts.

Comment: And how can I mount it on web?, Should I use Django Framework?, What do you think are the best tools for using it? From frameworks to databases.

Answer (score 2):

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is designed for this sort of thing.

Before scaping HTML however, check if the website offers an API. If so, you're already in business!

Comment: The websites I want to extract the information does not have any API, layouts has not been changed since 3 years ago and I don't think they are gonna change it.

Answer (score 2):

Python has great web scraping features: urllib, BeautifulSoup, XPath, etc. This video will get you started quickly with python web scraping: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ap_DlSrT-iE -  He's using urllib and BeautifulSoup to scrape [huffingtonposts](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/)' feed in his sample script.

If you want a scraping system (scraper with web front-end and admin to publish your scraped content), this might be a good option for you - https://github.com/holgerd77/django-dynamic-scraper - I would highly suggest this if you're already familiar with Django.

Comment: Thank you so much, if you have more of these resources I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) to request pages by URL, and then using [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to extract data.  This works well if the data is in small clumps.  The code reads fairly well: if line contains /regex/, store the value.

Comment: What's the difference between BeautifulSoap and urllib2?

Comment: You asked the wrong question. In this case, BeautifulSoup and regex would be what is being compared. The difference is that BeautifulSoup tries to parse the entire HTML response and make sense of it as a structured document tree. A simple regex would evaluate the HTML data, scanning for the specified sequence of characters. As the author suggests, possibly line by line.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some web spiders to gather some data from other website.By using urllib2 or requests can help you download the html from the website.Beautiful or PyQuery can help you parse the html and get the data you want.